# Identifiying a zip file that is not really a zip file

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have several files that a 3rd party program generated that have a .zip extension, however neither windows nor 7-Zip can extract it. In 7-Zip it does show me the file name of the uncompressed file however when I try to extract it I get the error

> An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.

I ran the file through [TrID.NET](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html), however it had not even a partial match on what the file was.

Here is the fist 51 bytes of the file.

```
offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
   hex: 14 00 08 00 08 00 C2 43 C6 3E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 31 30 35 36 30 36 2D 32 30 31 31 30 36 30 33 31 33 34 31 34 36 2E 65 6E 63
 ascii: .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  >  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  0  5  6  0  6  -  2  0  1  1  0  6  0  3  1  3  4  1  4  6  .  e  n  c
```

Here are the things I have figured out looking at severial files and comparing the headers:

- Bytes 0-5 are always `14 00 08 00 08 00` in the examples I checked
- Bytes 6-9 change per file, I don't think it is the uncompressed file size as it is much to big.
- Bytes 10-21 are always `00` in the examples I checked
- Bytes 22-25 is the length of the filename of the compressed file.
- Bytes 26-50 is the compressed file name (`105606-20101020162359.enc` in this example)

Everything after the file name appears to be different per compressed file.

Does anyone know what this fileformat is?

Comment: I wonder if it's not a regular .ZIP file with the headers intentionally mangled as a form of protection?  Have you tried running any "ZIP File Repair" tools on the archive?  They might be able to rebuild the directory, find the data, and extract the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some searching, and it appears that it *might* be a .JAR.

A .JAR's identifier is: `50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00` ([source](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html), search for JAR)

Which is the only partial match I could find.

This could also explain why you can't read it; part of the identifier is missing.

Comment: Even so, 7zip (and windows) have no trouble with JAR, so I don't know. If it is a .JAR what can I use to extract it?

Comment: You sir, are a genius, I used a hex editor to add in the missing `50 4B 03 04` and 7zip extracted the file.

Comment: Google is the actual genius here :) But thank you for the nice words!

Comment: In case anyone was curious, after hooking [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to the program I found out that it was calling `zip.dll` from the Java SE Runtime, so that explains the .JAR connection!